# Access to my new wordpress site on my Ubuntu server at home only shows my Apache2 default page

Tags: apache2, wordpress

I'll confess - I'm a newbie and trying to learn this new world of Ubuntu and web functions by installing it on my own network and exploring. So sorry if my questions seem odd or out of alignment.

My current problem:
I can access my new website (built on Wordpress) "locally" - from a browser on another PC attached to my home network. But I cannot access the same website remote. Instead of the website showing, I get the Apache2 Default Page.

Background:
When installing Ubuntu, Apache, PHP, SQL and Wordpress - I took all the defaults. So "locally" - everything is installed on a PC on my home network at 10.0.0.200.  And when I access it locally, I enter "10.0.0.200/wordpress" and everything looks great.

$curl ifconfig.me  ==>  01.02.03.04  (made up #'s)

I also Port Forwarded 80 and 443 in my Router for 10.0.0.200.

But now, from outside my local network (e.g. externally connected to the internet) when I enter in the browser "01.02.03.04/wordpress" - it spins for 30 seconds and finally comes back with:

The connection has timed out.
The server at "10.0.0.200" is taking too long to respond.

Also, when I enter 01.02.03.04 by itself, I get the Apache2 Default Page - which tells me port forwarding is at least working.

Do I need to do something with my index file? Or something in the 000-default.conf file to redirect it to my site?

And can I use PuTTY or FileZilla Client to remotely administer the Ubuntu server?

Thanks!

Thanks for your response Matigo. Very much appreciated.
Unfortunately (because of Covid I'm remote) I'm not in front of my web server - so I can't pull up and display the 000-default.conf file. Unless you know how I can connect with PuTTY or FileZilla? Otherwise, we'll have to wait 4-5 days until I can pull it up and send.

BTW - I suspect your intuition is correct and the problem lies in 000-default.conf. Makes sense.

I checked 000-default.conf. It only contains the defaults when you initially set it up:

<VirtualHost *:80>

```
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

Comment: Can you update your question to include the contents of the `000-default.conf` file? The issue is most likely in there and could be as simple to solve as adding/modifying a `ServerAlias` line.

Comment: I've added the contents of the 000-default.conf file (above). Do I need to add a ServerAlias line?